Italian movie about a man who might become a king
During a street festival in Romania I encountered an interesting movie whilst wondering around. The movie is likely to have been released in Italy. The audio language of the film sounded like Italian. There were English and Romanian subtitles displayed simultaneously as the movie played.
The film starts with a funeral. Then the son of the person who died goes to inspect the house of his deceased father, and noticed that people are bowing to him whenever he looks at them. It turns out that his dad was some kind of king which makes him a prince, so he can choose to claim the throne.
The son wants to sell the house but discovers that according to the law he cannot or that it would be difficult because it is owned by him and all the subjects.
I do not know the year of release but I suspect it may have been in the last decade or two, there is a scene where the prince is in the bath and receives a call from his wife on a mobile phone, the phone did not appear to be a smart phone. While he was talking to her two young ladies enter the bathroom, take off their clothes and then get into the tub with him and start to help him bathe while he talks to his wife, he doesn't say anything to them, but is clearly not happy that they are there, his wife then happens to ask him if there are any maids, at which point he lies and says that there are only two male servants, a few seconds later one of the young ladies puts her hand into the water and the prince panics, as he moves to stop her hand from going too close to him, he accidentally drops the phone into the water, this causes the phone to stop working, he then politely asks the young ladies to leave.
After the bath scene, he was walking through the fields of the estate and talking to a special holy kind of old guy who was telling him how much land there was and explaining a few things about his responsibilities as a monarch, there were two young men following him as they talk, suddenly the two young men and the older guy rush off to the side and start watching something, the prince goes over to see what they are doing and witnesses two men taking part in a duel with pistols, one of the men turns around and shoots the other, the old guy then explains that duels are the standard way to solve matters of honour and love. The next scene shows the prince running away with a suitcase towards a gate, he encounters a woman there and she explains that the duels do not result in death, though there are mild injuries, because blanks are used. I then had to leave for various reasons, but I took a photo just before I left:

Please tell me the name of this film, I would like to know about it so that I can finish watching it one day.

Do you mean deceased rather than diseased? The first means "dead", the second does not.
